# How do I get the type definition for this (Miranda functional programming )?

Tags: functional-programming

rcons s f z = f(s:z)

I need to get the type definition of the above, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

start with the `:` - it hints that if `s :: a` then `z::[a]` - now `f` needs to have `f :: [t] -> b`

---

collection this the answer is

```
recons :: a  -> ([a] -> b)  -> [a]  -> b
          ^     ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^     ^
        from s   from f         z   result of f
```

---

## Step by Step

If you are given an exercise like this you first have to identify where to start.

### the function

An obvious place is to find out a basic signature for your function.

So look at `rcons s f z = ...` this tells you that you define a function (named `rcons`) that takes 3 *arguments* (`s`, `f` and `z`) - the basic for for this is:

```
rcons :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

note that you don't know anything about the types (yet) so you just give them all different names (including the return-type `d`)

### look at the RHS

now let's look more closely to the right-hand-side: the first thing you see is that you have `f (..)` so it seems as `f` is itself a function that gets applied to the things in the parentheses.

This tells you that `f` itself has the form `f :: r -> s` so the type `b` from above is `b ~ r -> s`

Now if we replace this we are at

```
rcons :: a -> (r -> s) -> c -> d
```

Note that `f` is the last thing you do in `rcons`? This of course means that the result type `d` of `rcons` must be the same as the result-type of `f` (`s ~ d`) and you get

```
rcons :: a -> (r -> d) -> c -> d
```

### the argument of `f`

inside the parentheses you see the cons operation `:` which has the type `t -> [t] -> [t]` for some `t` - if you compare this with what you plug in : `s :: a`, `z :: c` you see that `t ~ a` and `[t] ~ c` but if `t ~ a` then `[t] ~ [a]` so now `c ~ [a]` and you have

```
rcons :: a -> (r -> d) -> [a] -> d
```

and you know the type of `s:z` as well - it's `[a]` too (the result from the cons)

### back to f

now that you know more about the input type to `f` you have `r ~ [a]` because the input-type of `f` must match with the type of what you give it`

you end with

```
 rcons :: a -> ([a] -> d) -> d
```

at this point we used every information we had we cannot go on - I would call it a day and promote this to the *answer*

Comment: * -> (*  -> [ * ]  -> [ * ] )  ->[ * ] -> [ * ]

Comment: those are kinds ... you are asking for types ... I did give you almost the complete answer - you just have to collect the parts and put them in the right order with `->`

Comment: How can one tell from the question f takes in an array of type a and returns something that is not a array of type b ?, Also does f not take in 2 parameters s and z ?

Comment: @user63377 There are no arrays. `s:z` is a list (you can tell from the `:`). A type variable like `b` designates any type – it could be a list, and it could be something else. (It seems like you're not very comfortable with the basic syntax yet, and that makes it much harder to reason about types.)

Comment: @user63377 - **1.** you can tell that `f` has an input of type `[a]` because you use it with `f (s:z)` and here `s:z` is it's only arguments and needs to have type `[a]` (when `s::a` because `(:)` is `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`) - **2.** as you can see from the parentheses on the right hand side `f` only takes one argument (well you can argue that every function in Haskell only takes 1) - the `f` on the left hand side is an argument to `rcons`

Comment: no sorry I don't know why I said array I meant list the first time,

Comment: Ok I understand better now why F takes only 1 argument, but then how can you tell it returns of type b which is not part of a list?  also why is the s on the LHS of type a but with f on the RHS is a list. Lastly how does one know z from the LHS is a list of type a ?

Comment: please have a look on my updated answer - the thing with `b` is that you cannot tell! That's why you choose some name first and then try to unify them

Comment: also: `s` is *not* a list - on the RHS it's used with `s : z` ... please look at the definition of `(:)` - is the `1` in `1 : [2]` a list? (of course it can be a list - it's generic - but if `s` is  a list than `z` has to be a list of a list - and `f` has to act on lists-of-lists ...)

Comment: maybe your main problem is that you cannot see that a type-parameter like `a` can stand for every other type - it can be an `Int`, a `[Int]` or a `Int -> Float`, `IO (Int -> String -> ())`, ...

Comment: The only bit of your updated answer I cannot understand is why if on the RHS s:z should not z be a list and f adding a new element s to that list using : ?

Comment: @user63377 `z` should have type `[a]` so it's a list - where is the line (maybe I messed up)?